# dns probe finished nxdomain linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, server, network-manager, dns, troubleshooting

I'm having problems with my DNS in Ubuntu. The webpage won't show up. I've been trouble shooting for hours.

I have tried clearing the cache but none of the commands work.

I have tried it this way below and it hasn't worked. The restart commands don't work.

Resolved: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in Linux

- Step 1. Open terminal and add below command

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

- Step 2. Now add below line in file

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```

Now, save file

- Step 3. Restart the network

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

I have also tried it this way: `sudo vim` doesn't work but `sudo nano` does when I insert the nameservers and hit Ctrl+X Y enter the nameservers I added don't save and once again none of the commands to restart the system work.

for Ubuntu 20.04 run below command: `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf` . If above does not work run `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`  Add below name servers to file and refresh the page will work fine: `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 208.67.222.222 nameserver 4.2.2.2`

I have also tried clearing Chrome's cache, restarting my router, and restarting my computer. Nothing that I have tried on any website or forum has worked so far.

Comment: How do you know you have a DNS problem? What is the exact problem that you are experiencing? What website are you talking about? What do you mean when you say commands don't work? You've given us a lot of information that you found that are instructions to run commands, but you haven't actually given any details about the results of running those commands. It's best that you include the output of any commands that "don't work" so we can review the actual errors. Please do not forget to [format](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) your post so that we can understand it.

Comment: Does `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` return pings? How about: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` We needn't see the entire result; just yes or no. Please edit your question to show the result of: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Go to terminal window and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

after gedit is open go to the last line, you'll see nameserver and your current dns ip address. replace it with 94.140.14.14 and save it.
that's it, although you can use any dns ip address you like.

Comment: This will be ineffective in all recent, that is, not end-of-life installs. The file itself clearly says: `Do not edit.` The sytemd mechanism will rewrite the file upon reboot. The changes will be lost.